# Hide custom navigation buttons if carousel has less items to show - Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using owl carousel on one of the pages and I am using following script from theme unify http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.7/shortcode_carousels.html

I want to hide the navigation buttons when the carousel has fewer items to show even in responsive mode something similar to what has been done in this example http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/qhgjb?editors=101, in this codepen example button hide based on items visible in different screen sizes.

I tried to implement the same to the carousel but it is not working for me

fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpYKvq

```
    //Owl Slider v1
    var owl = jQuery(".owl-slider").owlCarousel({
        itemsDesktop : [1000,5],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,4],
        itemsTablet: [600,3],
        itemsMobile : [479,2],
    });
    jQuery(".next-v1").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
    })
    jQuery(".prev-v1").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.prev');
    })
```

Comment: you can manually set breakpoint options in your carousel http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you still need it, but (just in case) if it's just the *buttons* that you'd like to hide, you can check the window width (like @Mohamed-Yousef's example) and then just do a `.hide()`. This is how it should *roughly* look like:

```js
var viewport = jQuery(window).width();
var itemCount = jQuery("#owl-demo div").length;

if(
    (viewport >= 900 && itemCount > 5) //desktop
    || ((viewport >= 600 && viewport < 900) && itemCount > 4) //desktopsmall
    || ((viewport >= 479 && viewport < 600) && itemCount > 3) //tablet
    || (viewport < 479 && itemCount > 2) //mobile
)
{
     jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').hide();
} 
else
{
     jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').show();
}
```

Make sure that this runs on document load and whatever other events would trigger changes in the carousel.

I'd also just like to mention that I made assumptions about how your code looks like via the code snippet you gave in your question above, and *not* from the fiddle you gave as the two are different from each other. The fiddle is what I think @Mohamed-Yousef was basing his answer from, as it *looks* like the default implementation of owl carousel (I didn't check it thoroughly though), while the one in your question looks like a manually implemented custom button that is set to trigger the owl.next/owl.prev events.

Comment: I've exchanged `hide()` and `show()` parts. It's working for me after made the changes :)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but also looked for a solution and found one in pure CSS, so maybe it will be useful for someone in future. To hide one dot we can use :only-child pseudo-class. The problem is that it's not supported well (only chrome), so better one is to use an alias of it ":first-child:last-child":

```
.owl-dot:first-child:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply check the number of Divs by using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
  if($("#owl-demo div").length + 1 > 5){
  carousel.owlCarousel({
    navigation:true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
  });
  }

});
```

this check if more than 5 divs run owlCarousel and for  responsive mode  you need to check for `$(window).width();`  for example

```
if($(window).width() > 800 && $(window).width() < 1400){ // for desktop
    if($("#owl-demo div").length + 1 > 5){
        // run carousel....
    }
}else if($(window).width() > 600 && $(window).width() < 800){ // for Tab
   if($("#owl-demo div").length + 1 > 4){ // change it as your screen size
        // run carousel....
    }
}
```

and so on

Comment: Script which you have use is working in the actual example i want to apply same feature to the custom navigation as mentioned in the question. This needs to be calculated for each screen size let is say on we only have 3 items and on desktop version it show 5 items in this case it should hide nav, and show nav on mobile version as it shows only 1 items ..

Comment: auto hide seems to be built in option in the actual script but i am not able to find a way to apply same for custom nav buttons

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker  I will look for autohide option

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker look man as this http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to  .. I think there is no way to do what you want by using options .. there is just autoPlay option which will not hide the buttons .. But logically why they make option to hide the buttons if they offer the owlCarousel to change between images and if you not have a good number of images to change through so no need to use owlCarousel .. I will keep searching about that and if I got any news I will tell you .. good luck :)

Comment: Actually i have several carousal on a page which show videos like show on YouTube and in my case my not all of my playlist under carousal will have enough videos as it is dynamically generated in case it is less for any specific screen size then it should hide nav buttons, I hope you got my point why i want to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var owl = jQuery(".owl-slider").owlCarousel({
    itemsDesktop: [1000, 5],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 4],
    itemsTablet: [600, 3],
    itemsMobile: [479, 2],
    afterInit: function() {
        var viewport = jQuery(window).width();
        var itemCount = jQuery(".owl-slider div").length;

        if ((viewport >= 900 && itemCount > 5) //desktop
            || ((viewport >= 600 && viewport < 900) && itemCount > 4) //desktopsmall
            || ((viewport >= 479 && viewport < 600) && itemCount > 3) //tablet
            || (viewport < 479 && itemCount > 2) //mobile
        ) {
            jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').hide();
        }
    },
    afterUpdate: function() {
        var viewport = jQuery(window).width();
        var itemCount = jQuery("#owl-demo div").length;

        if (
            (viewport >= 900 && itemCount > 5) //desktop
            || ((viewport >= 600 && viewport < 900) && itemCount > 4) //desktopsmall
            || ((viewport >= 479 && viewport < 600) && itemCount > 3) //tablet
            || (viewport < 479 && itemCount > 2) //mobile
        ) {
            jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.next-v1, .prev-v1').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bootstrap 3, you can try my solution which is based on reponsive classes.
It doesnt need additional listener on resize or other events and is executed on initialize. Moreover its quite simple.

```
        var $el = $('.my-carousel');
        var breakpoints = {
            0: {
                items: 3
            },
            480: {
                items: 4
            },
            769: {
                items: 5
            },
            992: {
                items: 4
            },
            1200: {
                items: 5
            }
        };
        var carousel = $el.owlCarousel({
            loop:   true,
            margin: 10,
            nav:    false,
            dots:   false,
            responsive: breakpoints
        });

        // get real items count
        var items   = $el.find('.owl-item:not(.cloned)').length;

        // $nav = your navigation element, mine is custom
        var $nav    = $el.parent().find('.center-navigation');

        // add responsive classes to hide navigation if needed
        if(breakpoints[1200].items>=items)  $nav.addClass('hidden-lg');
        if(breakpoints[992].items>=items)   $nav.addClass('hidden-md');
        if(breakpoints[769].items>=items)   $nav.addClass('hidden-sm');
        if(breakpoints[480].items>=items)   $nav.addClass('hidden-xs');
        if(breakpoints[0].items>=items)     $nav.addClass('hidden-xxs');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```js
  function HideNavigationInCarousel(ContainerdivId,viewport)
    {
          
        var itemCount = jQuery("#" + ContainerdivId +" .owl-item").length;

       // console.log(ContainerdivId + " " + viewport+ " "+itemCount);


        if (viewport / itemCount > (jQuery("#" + ContainerdivId + " .owl-item").width()))
       
        {
            jQuery("#" + ContainerdivId + " .owl-prev,"+"#" + ContainerdivId +" .owl-next").hide();
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#" + ContainerdivId + ".owl-prev,"+"#" + ContainerdivId +" .owl-next").show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using responsive options, I suggest adding or removing a *disabled* class on prev/next button, when it's not active.

```
jQuery(".owl-slider")
.on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel refreshed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    if (!event.namespace) return;
    var carousel = event.relatedTarget,
        element = event.target,
        current = carousel.current();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.owl-next', element).toggleClass('disabled', current === carousel.maximum());
        $('.owl-prev', element).toggleClass('disabled', current === carousel.minimum());        
    }, 1);
})
.owlCarousel({
    itemsDesktop : [1000,5],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [900,4],
    itemsTablet: [600,3],
    itemsMobile : [479,2],
});
```

In CSS, you can either hide *disabled* element or change its style.
Here's my SASS code for *disabled* class CSS  :

```
.owl-next,
.owl-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    &.disabled {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the simplest way I found to do it, is to use owlCarousel own vars:

```
function toggleArrows(){
    var c = $('.carousel').data('owlCarousel');
    if(c.options.items==c.itemsAmount){
        $('.next, .prev').hide();
    }else{
        $('.next, .prev').show();
    }
}
```

Owl carousel will update his internal var options.items based on the number of visible items.

You can run this on the window resize event, just be careful with the responsiveRefreshRate, which update the vars each 200ms (by default), so I run this code inside a timeout after window resize.

```
var tmtResize = false;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(tmtResize) clearTimeout(tmtResize);
    tmtResize = setTimeout(function(){
        toggleArrows();
    }, 250);
});
```